# How to get Usb camera frames in c++

Tags: c++, windows, usb

I have a usb camera, now I have to find if the camera is connected in my computer(Windows), If connected, I have to send the frames, how can I do in c++ without opencv....

Comment: it is hard to do without opencv, why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: actually don't want the dependency,, that's why do you know like libv4l like Linux??

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the Windows API for performing IO on cameras, but I think that you might find [Capturing Video from Web-camera on Windows 7 and 8 by using Media Foundation](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/559437/Capturing-Video-from-Web-camera-on-Windows-and-by) interesting. The author used to depend on [videoInput](https://github.com/ofTheo/videoInput) but then resorted to implementing his own lib.

You can also find a detailed (but old) tutorial [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/193519-win32-webcam-program/).